# What does this 3 means in staff notation?

Tags: notation, tuplet

Does anyone know what does this 3 means in staff notation as shown below in the image, why there is more than 3 bits.
[image]

Comment: This is the sign for triplets what means there are 3 eight notes for a quaver. (The first two are tied).

Comment: Yes, a crotchet - as Tim writes. Not a quaver (I thought this was the term for a 4th note

Answer (score 3):

There *are* three bits - 'le-et me'. That one beat - here a crotchet, is split into three equal parts. They're known as triplets. So 'soul' has the first two beats of that bar to be sung to, and the last beat is now three equal notes, taking exactly the same time as one beat together.

Probably a dupe, though!